# Drop Down Menu not sticking to LI Parent

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down menu that looks great when the page it scrolled to the very top, but when I scroll down, the second `<li>` parent's drop down scrolls up with the page instead of sticking with the parent element.

RESOLVED: Second drop menu wasn't inside the parent header div.

The top link CREATE works fine, but the link MANAGE is the `<li>` parent with the problem.

Here is the link to the JS: http://www.brandonrray.com/Heriyah/admin/system/js/chrome.js

Here is the CSS:

```
ul {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
ul li {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
.chromestyle{
width: 99%;
font-weight: bold;
cursor:pointer;
}
.chromestyle:after{ /*Add margin between menu and rest of content in Firefox*/
content: "."; 
display: block; 
height: 0; 
clear: both; 
visibility: hidden;
}
.chromestyle ul{
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
text-align: right;
}
.chromestyle ul li{
display: inline;
}
.chromestyle ul li a{
color: #494949;
padding-left:15px;
padding-right:15px;
padding-top:20px;
padding-bottom:20px;
margin: 0;
text-decoration: none;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
color:#FFFFFF;
}
.chromestyle ul li a:hover, .chromestyle ul li a.selected{
background-color:#0abbe1;
}
/* ######### Style for Drop Down Menu ######### */
.dropmenudiv{
cursor:pointer;
position:absolute;
top: 0;
border: 1px solid #BBB; /*THEME CHANGE HERE*/
border-bottom-width: 0;
font:normal 12px Verdana;
line-height:24px;
z-index:100;
background-color: white;
width: 200px;
visibility: hidden;
}
.dropmenudiv a{
width: auto;
display: block;
text-indent: 3px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #BBB; /*THEME CHANGE HERE*/
padding: 2px 0;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
padding-left:15px;
}
* html .dropmenudiv a{ /*IE only hack*/
width: 100%;
}
.dropmenudiv a:hover{ /*THEME CHANGE HERE*/
background-color: #0abbe1; color:#FFFFFF
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely at the html source you'll find that `dropmenu2` is in the wrong place.

This is your code

```
<div>
   ...
   <div id="dropmenu1">...</div>
</div>
<div id="dropmenu2">...</div>
```

Dropmenu 2 should in the same place as dropmenu1

```
<div>
   ...
   <div id="dropmenu1">...</div>
   <div id="dropmenu2">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why isn't dropmenu2 under the same parent as dropmenu1?  Only dropmenu1 is a child of the heriyah_header div.